# Notation for pdf of normal distribution

Tags: probability, notation

Suppose I want to notate "the density of normal probability distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ computed for value $x$",

is there a commonly accepted way to notate this succinctly, along the lines of

$ PDF_{\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)}(x) $

Update:

Although $\phi$ is conventional I was hoping for some notation that generalizes elegantly to any other named distribution, e.g. so it would be possible to change to exponential by changing $\mathcal{N}$ for $\mathcal{EXP}$, or suchlike?

Comment: You mean like $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ ?

Comment: You are right I meant $\sigma^2$ but I didn't mean ~ - see Jordan's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple ${\cal N}(x|\mu, \sigma^2)$ will suffice:
$$
{\cal N}(x|\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}
$$
where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are given on the side meaning you treat them as known quantities.